# How to call URL without Localhost?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http, url

I am working on User management page in this,i want to store selected permissions in DB table .My code is following

```
   ...
    callajax("POST", "Permissions Details added Successfully.",formData);
    }
    var url= "http://localhost:8080/collection-ui/api/rolepermissions/updprm";   

   function callajax(posttype,successMsg,formData)
   {
    $.ajax({
    type : posttype,
    url : url,
    data : JSON.stringify(formData),    
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success : function(response) {
        if(response.status == "Success"){
```

Its working perfectly but this is working only in my system because the URL is Localhost right, then how can i call the url without localhost.plz anybody help

Comment: look for your IP.....  then wrile URL like this... [http://192.168.***.***/yourpath/filename.php]

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var url= "api/rolepermissions/updprm";
```

Of course, you have to call ajax on the same machine as your websever, else you will have `same origin policy` problems

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to a relative path, the domain/location won't be an issue as long as the directory structure stays the same.

```
var url= "/collection-ui/api/rolepermissions/updprm";
```

Answer (score 0):

1> Use relative path.

2> Use IP address instead of 'localhost'

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var url= location.host+"/collection-ui/api/rolepermissions/updprm";
```

Hope this works.